# Edge/Chrome not sending ETag in If-None-Match header

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In the enterprise Intranet, there is this web application that is being served through Nginx.  Nginx is generating the **ETag** HTTP header as expected.

However, upon re-visiting or refreshing the web application, the browser (Chrome or Edge) is not sending the **ETag** in the **If-None-Match** HTTP request header.

Is this a setting somewhere?  Or how can I start to look for the problem?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should just make sure the **Disable cache** option is **unchecked**:
[image]

Additionally, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52784928/19697081) if the solution above does not work for you.